# How is this 1 input 2 output tx larger than this 2 input 2 output tx?

Tags: confidential-transactions, transaction-weight, liquid

I saw the following liquid transaction with one input and two outputs is byte-wise bigger than another liquid transaction with two inputs and two outputs. How is this possible?

One input transaction (2772 vB): https://blockstream.info/liquid/tx/35d4db9621c70d3bcfe258487fd74447e12f5c9b71b3161e22e15bdeb157eea8

Two input transaction (2102 vB):
https://blockstream.info/liquid/tx/75621a91c3b3d779c646ecfd8278462040e743ef6535343ae0dc41e2ed7b6fa8

Comment: One has an asset creation commitment and one doesn’t.

Comment: I was confused when I read your question, but looking at the two transactions, I think you meant "bigger" rather than "smaller? I've updated your question. Please check whether I got it right! :)

Comment: Yes that's correct, thank you for that!:)